# Constructor Console() is not visible

Tags: java, console

I get the feeling once someone answers this question, I will feel a little stupid.

Regardless, I just downloaded Java 7.5 and I am immediately a encountering problem that did not exist before the download.

I was about to write a quick program to do something. To do what is, for once definitely, irrelevant. I set about starting this by initiating the console.

Literally all I had written was:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Console console = new Console();
}
```

I encountered this error

> The constructor Console() is not visible

Before I updated Java, I had only encountered this due to my own error.

Has the `Console` constructor's modifier been changed in this update? I'm assuming not.

If the `Console` class has been changed, what is the correct syntax now?

Comment: Are you talking about [`java.io.Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)? That one never had a public constructor, as far as I know. Or are you talking about some other class with that name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) for this kind of information. It will tell you there is in fact no visible constructor, and that an instance "can be obtained by invoking the `System.console()` method".

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke [System.console()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) to retreive the object:

Answer (score 0):

You should use: [Console con = System.console();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29)

Answer (score -1):

public final class Console
extends Object
implements Flushable

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/Console.html